# Getting pairs of: one item and the rest, over a python list

Tags: python, performance

I want to do this

```py
from some_cool_library import fancy_calculation

arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i, item in enumerate(arr):
    the_rest = arr[:i] + arr[i+1:]
    print(item, fancy_calculation(the_rest))


[Expected output:] # some fancy output from the fancy_calculation
12.13452134
2416245.4315432
542.343152
15150.1152
10.1591
```

But I wonder if there is a more pythonic way or existing library to get pairs as shown above.

The problem with the current implementation is that we need about O(n) more memory for the `the_rest` variable. Is there any way on how we can do this without additional memory allocation?

```py
for item, the_rest in some_cool_function(arr):
    print(item, fancy_calculation(the_rest))
```

Comment: Your current approach is fine. Don't prematurely optimise.

Comment: 'Fine' depends on requirements, my array is about 1 GB in memory size.

Comment: It's impossible to beat `O(n^2)` because you are printing precisely `n^2` elements. You could avoid the overhead of allocating a new list by using `itertools.chain`, but to reap the benefits you would have to call `print` separately on each element which in itself could be a bottleneck.

Comment: Yes I just realized the minimum O(n^2) time complexity if we are processing all elements within the `the_rest`. Regarding the `itertools.chain`, so I use `itertools.chain(arr[:i], arr[i+1:])`?

Comment: Beware that `arr[:i]` also creates a new list (if `arr` is a vanilla Python list; `numpy` arrays support `O(1)` slicing). Use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to create an iterator over the slice.

Comment: I see, then we should be able to solve it now. Do you mind writing an answer?

Comment: Would it be ok to modify `a_sum_function` to have 1 more arg where you can tell the function to skip a specific index. For e.g. `a_sum_function(arr, i)` where you can choose to skip the item at index `i`.

Comment: I still don't see why you would want to print a ~ 1 GB `n`-element array `n` times (the end product could contain *tens of trillions* of elements - far more than any terminal can display or an average computer's RAM can store). Are you in-fact doing something else with the data, e.g. writing directly to a file?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, 1) @shahkalpesh that would be ok for this specific case, but not in general (e.g. when I don't have access to the `a_sum_function`). 2) @meowgoesthedog I don't want to print, just calculate something. sorry for the bad example illustration. Your solution with `itertools.chain(itertools.islice(arr, i), itertoole.islice(arr, i+1, None))` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

if you only need the rest (as seems from your edit) you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to get all combinations with certain number of elements, like this:

```py
from itertools import combinations

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for combination in combinations(arr, len(arr)-1):
    print(sum(combination))
```

NOTE: the order is reverse from what you supplied, if the order matters you can reverse arr before using `arr[::-1]`

Comment: Oh sorry I actually need both the item and the rest

Comment: Oh @KevinWinata then `combinations` doesn't do that :( nor any other iterfunc  I'm aware of... but your original solution is nice, readable, and does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of "pythonicity" and readability, I'd say your code is fine as it is.

If you're concerned with the list allocations in the loop, you can optimize like this:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

the_rest = arr[1:]
for i, item in enumerate(arr):
    print(item, fancy_calculation(the_rest))

    if i < len(arr) - 1:
        the_rest[i] = arr[i]
```

Remember though: `fancy_calculation` will be getting the same list reference in each iteration, so: (a) don't modify it and (b) don't defer calculation (e.g. separate consumer thread) as the content will change in the next iteration.